# In a json, find a key which contains value as 'RBS' and then replace the value 'RBS' in another key which has the same digits at the end in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this JSON data and key "Label_Field_ID_1117189" has values "RBS" and I need to replace the value "RBS" in another key "User_Answer_Field_ID_1117189" which has the same digit at last i.e 1117189. and also same with the  "Label_Field_ID_1117230" and replace the value "RBS" in "User_Answer_Field_ID_1117230".
Need the logic in Node js

```
[
  {
    "Author": "rps",
    "Label_Field_ID_1117189": "RBS",
    "User_Answer_Field_ID_1117189": "4532019166",
    "status": "In Bearbeitung"
  },
  {
    "Author": "sps",
    "Label_Field_ID_1117230": "RBS",
    "User_Answer_Field_ID_1117230": "4232019179"
  }
]
```

I need Json to look like this below

```
[
  {
    "Author": "rps",
    "Label_Field_ID_1117189": "RBS",
    "RBS": "4532019166",
    "status": "In Bearbeitung"
  },
  {
    "Author": "sps",
    "Label_Field_ID_1117230": "RBS",
    "RBS": "4232019179"
  }
]
```

Comment: and what have you tried to make the JSON as you want?

Comment: why is `User_Answer_Field_ID_1117189` not replaced, but `User_Answer_Field_ID_1117230` is? there's no sense to what you want to achieve, since you contradict yourself by mentioning that `User_Answer_Field_ID_1117189` should be replaced, but in your required output it isn't

Comment: yeah you are correct, actually both the keys should be replaced in that json array. Now  I have edited/updated my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a mapping function `updateAnswerFields` or similar to process each object, replacing the answer field with the correct value from the corresponding label field.

We'd use Object.entries() to find the label and value to use when replacing the answer field.

The answer ID will be the same as the label ID, so we'll compose this using the ID value from the label.

We'll use the de-structuring assignment to remove the answer label from the returned object, then update with the label value.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "Author": "rps",
    "Label_Field_ID_1117189": "RBS",
    "User_Answer_Field_ID_1117189": "4532019166",
    "status": "In Bearbeitung"
  },
  {
    "Author": "sps",
    "Label_Field_ID_1117230": "RBS",
    "User_Answer_Field_ID_1117230": "4232019179"
  }
]

function updateAnswerFields(obj) {
    const [ label, value] = Object.entries(obj).find(([key, value]) => key.startsWith('Label_Field_ID_'));
    const answerKey = 'User_Answer_Field_ID_'  + label.split('_').slice(-1)[0];
    const { [answerKey]: a, ...rest} = obj;
    rest[value] = obj[answerKey]
    return rest;
}

console.log(input.map(updateAnswerFields));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```